# Hiding more than one view in spinner list in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I am trying to generate spinner list in a recyclerview, where there is a fixed string list for the spinner adapter. I want show in my app something like this-

1. when first-time spinner item is clicked in the recyclerview it will show the full list. Then if the user selects a value for the first row's spinner item in the recyclerview and then click the second row's spinner item in the recyclerview user will not see the first row's selected spinner item in the second rows vice versa for third row's of the recyclerview. Here I have attached screenshots[image].

[image]